# Understanding x86 r/m32 instruction

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, static-analysis, ida

I have this piece of x86 assembler code:

```
mov edx, off_984C400
mov eax, [edx+1E0h]
call eax
```

The OpenSecurityTraining-Videos teached me that `[something]` meants that the processor tries to access memory at the position `something`.
That would mean `move 0x984C400 into edx, add 0x1E0 to it and call whatever address there is in memory`.

My problem now is, that I only have static analysis via IDA available and don't know how I can find out what address is at `[0x984C400 + 0x1E0]`. Is there any way I can get the static address of the function?

Comment: The title ask a different question from the body. What can't you understand about the indirect addressing mode? IDA is usually very good a finding the indirect targets, if it doesn't suggest anything then probably the target depends on the program states and the easier way to know what it is, is breaking just before the call. You can see all the cross reference to *off_984c400* and hope for a few results to be helpful

Comment: `0x1E0` is 480... that's quite some offset from `off_984C400`, so cross references to `off_984C400` may not reveal the code which is preparing the address (if it is dynamically written into memory at `0x984C5E0` by some other code). If you would be able to debug the code, it would be probably easier to put a memory-write breakpoint there to see how the address is set (if it's not static, then breakpoint ahead of call suffice to reveal it all, like Margaret suggests).

Comment: `Is there any way I can get the static address of the function?`  Unlikely.  If there was only one possible destination, the code probably wouldn't be using an indirect `call` in the first place.  The exception to that would be for library function calls, where dynamic linking is done with a level of indirection instead of by rewriting `call rel32` encodings throughout the executable, on typical OSes.

Answer (score 4):

First off, your question has nothing to do with `r/m32`. `r/m32` is a syntax that represents that the operand of an instruction can be either a register or 32-bit memory address. See more details in volume 2A, section 3 of *Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual*

Second, `[something]` means take the address inside the brackets, and fetch the value from that address. In C, that would be called dereferencing a pointer. Just make mental note that this is not the case for the LEA instruction.

ex. `mov eax, 0x1004000` means move the value 0x1004000 into the eax register. Now, `mov ecx, [eax]` would fetch whatever 32-bit value is at RVA 0x1004000 and copy that into the ecx register.

Finally, you would get the address of the function exactly as you described. You walk through the instructions making note of what is saved where. I don't know why you call it the 'static' address.

Comment: I think the OP is hoping that they can figure out the final address of the called function (so they can disassemble it) *without* running the program.  The address is probably one of a few possible static blocks of code, but yeah the pointer itself is not static.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation would be that the address in question is either a `struct` that has a virtual function pointer (set somewhere else), or that it's a `vtable` (if it's C++). The pointer is probably in the data segment (check that yourself)

If it's a `struct` with virtual functions, check the address's `xref`s (and maybe of the addresses around it)

`vtable`s are initialized in `ctor`s, so in this case `xref`ing the address should get you to the `ctor`.

Anyway, remember that this call can be translated into more than one possible function.